# contextual meaning of "dynamics"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, ambiguity

In the following sentence, what is contextual meaning of "dynamics"?

> The sharing economy has sadly proven that the pathologies of the
> physical world all too often carry over to the platform, raising
> significant concerns for anti-discrimination law. Charlotte Garden and
> Nancy Leong begin the Handbook’s exploration of **these dynamics** by
> excavating the landscape of responsibility for platform companies.

Dynamics have several meanings and I presume dynamics is used as 'a pattern or process of change, growth, or activity' in the quoted sentence, but it's a little bit confusing or hard to understand what exactly corresponds to dynamics in the sentence.

Would it be the process that the pathologies of the physical world carry over to the platform?

Comment: If you can’t understand the description — and neither can I — I wouldn’t bother reading it. Sounds complete bullshit. Certainly not English.

Answer (score 1):

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dynamics), this is the closest definition:

[dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/dynamics?s=t) has a definition similar to the one you quoted, but also one that may be closer to the way it's being used in your quote:

> 2 (used with a plural verb) the motivating or driving forces, physical or moral, in any field.

It's referring to the complex relationships between all the economic and social processes and forces related to the sharing economy.